# Random increase in div height for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding html tags dynamically into a div, unless the div's height has reached 700px, after which I'm adding new tags to a separate div, like this:

```
while (index < contents.length) {
        var content = contents.eq(index).clone();
        var previousHeight = heightTesterDiv.height();
        heightTesterDiv.append(content);
        var newHeight = heightTesterDiv.height();
        console.log('Div content: '+content[0].outerHTML +' .Div Height Increased: '+(newHeight - previousHeight));

        if (heightTesterDiv.height() > 700) {
             // other code
        }
}
```

However, the increase in height after adding tags seems random: [image]

We can see that `<br>` is sometimes increasing the height by 0px, while sometimes by 30px.
Is this an expected behaviour ?

EDIT: Live fiddle: http://jsbin.com/semepejahu/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: What is purpose of calling `content.clone()` twice?

Comment: I've corrected it..

Comment: post a live snippet?

Comment: @mat You can the the fiddle at: http://jsbin.com/semepejahu/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this is the css display values at play here.

Some elements come with a few built in styles..for example some browsers give h1 and h4 tags "display: block;" styling by default.

The gist of the difference is that inline elements can be side by side and block is designed so the elements get their own "line". But for some reason these two values completely change how the styling margins work.

You can inspect/query the 'br' tags and always find they never have height,in either case...so you know they don't directly cause this issue.

If you add some css to your fiddle:

```
h1, h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

you'll notice the 'br' tags don't contribute more height. Elements with

```
display: block;
```

will cause the parent div to increase in size when pushed up against other elements due to this interpretation of margins. Even elements with no realistic size like our 'br' tags.

But yeah...why those amounts... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯